# Resizing NSData before converting to UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdata

I'm dealing with high resolution images that I'm downloading from an api. As I have no way of resizing the images on the server, I have to do it on the phone. The images are about 4000 x 4000 and above. I've spent the past couple of days playing around with resizing and cropping options that work very well once I've already converted the NSData into a UIImage by means of:

```
UIImage *yourImage = [UIImage imageWithData:yourData];
```

Unfortunately, just by loading the NSData into a UIImage, I already run into memory issues. Is there any way I can resize or manipulate the NSData before loading it into a UIImage?

Comment: The standard image resizing routines require you to load the image into a `UIImage` (or equivalent) object. Even if you knew exactly which format the payload was going to represented, to try to manipulate the raw binary data payload is a very complicated problem.

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured. I was just hoping there was something I missed from the documentation. Thank you. @Rob

Comment: Did you try imageWithData:scale:? That might help (if scale < 1).

Comment: @MichaelL, this actually looks perfect. Though I'd be interested to know how this works underneath. I wonder if it just converts to a UIImage first then scales that. From preliminary tests, my memory usage jumps to the same extent as it would if I were loading the large images.

Comment: I am not sure how it works underneath. Using the scale parameter, the implementation should be able to figure out the required dimensions of the image, and thus create the correctly sized CGBitMapImage. But maybe they were lazy.... Either way, the memory spike should be temporary.You could always go the CG route and do your own decoding. Its not that hard.